# Use li to select radio input buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a payment option buttons. The problem is the pre-made option gives no place to add payment images and descriptions. So I have made a (li) list of options using basic html and content now i want to know if we can make li to select input when pressed

[image: This is how current html looks]

HTML Code

```
<div class="shipping-method">
<ul class="">
    <li>
        <div class="item"><a href="javascript:;" class="weixin_wap">Wechat</a>
            <div class="disc"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item on"><a href="javascript:;" class="alipaywap">AliPay</a>
            <div class="disc">Discription goes here</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul></div>
```

Current Input Code

```
<div class="radio-buttons-selection">
<label>
    <input name="shipping" type="radio" class="radio" id="shipping_{$shipping.shipping_id}" value="{$shipping.shipping_id}" {if $order.shipping_id eq $shipping.shipping_id}checked="true" {/if} supportCod="{$shipping.support_cod}" insure="{$shipping.insure}" onclick="selectShipping(this)">
    <div class="shipping_{$shipping.shipping_id} box"> <span>{$shipping.shipping_name}</span> </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfortunately not quite sure how you have implemented your *Current input code* with the rest of the code. However, using the first snippet of code, something like this (using jQuery) should work:

```js
$("li").on("click", function() {
$("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
        });
  
        $(this).find("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shipping-method">
<ul class="">
    <li>
        <div class="item"><a href="#" class="weixin_wap">Wechat</a>
            <div class="disc"></div>
            <input type="radio"/>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item on"><a href="#" class="alipaywap">AliPay</a>
            <div class="disc">Discription goes here</div>
            <input type="radio"/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul></div>
```

Basically, if a list-item is clicked, find the input[type=radio] in that list item and check it (and before that, make sure all others are unchecked so we keep it 'valid').

If you can merge your HTML code with your *Current input code* I might be able to provide a better example, but nonetheless you might see what's going on and what you could do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".shipping-method li").on("click", function() {
$(".shipping-method input[type=radio]").each(function() {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
                $(this).children(".shipping-method .item").removeClass("on");
        });

        $(this).find("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", true);
        $(this).find(".item").addClass("on");
});
```

Comment: There is a addition of class when li is selected which is "on" so when the li is selected it should add class aswell

Answer (score 0):

**[:I assume the 'selectShipping' method will try to extract above
values(id,value,insure,supportCod) from  'this']**

**'Right Click' on browser & find out the following in run time the respective values for input element '*' that you are not able to customize:**

1.)$shipping.shipping_id=?? , value=??,supportCod=??,insure=??  Of first option
2.)$shipping.shipping_id=?? , value=??,supportCod=??, insure=?? Of second option

**elements into  elements containin as the selectShipping method expects it to be 
-->**

```
<div class="shipping-method">
    <ul class="">
        <li>
            <div class="item"><a href="javascript:;" class="weixin_wap" id="shipping_{$shipping.shipping_id_Of_firstoption}" value="{??Of_firstoption}" insure="{$shipping.insureOf_firstoption}" onclick="selectShipping(this)>Wechat</a>
                <div class="disc"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="item on"><a href="javascript:;" class="alipaywap" id="shipping_{$shipping.shipping_id_Of_second_option}" value="{??Of_second_option}" insure="{$shipping.insureOf_second_option}" onclick="selectShipping(this)>AliPay</a>
                <div class="disc">Discription goes here</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul></div>
```